# Почему возникает ошибка could not find driver при подключении к БД

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, pdo

При подключении к БД через PDO выдает такую ошибку: could not find driver. Работаю на Ubuntu 20.04 lts, PHP 8.1

```
<?php
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost", "root", "root");
    echo "Database connection";
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Выводит:

```
Connection failed: could not find driver
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Либо не установлено расширение php-pdo, либо не раскомментированно в php.ini в разделе dynamic extensions

Обычно автоматом ставится с расширением для работы с mysql

```
sudo apt-get install php8.1-mysql
```

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь выдает такую ошибку: Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES). Пароль верный. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Не вижу смысл обсуждать другую проблему в комментариях не связанной с ней темой